# JOOQ: Select, Modify and insert into the same table?

Tags: sql, jooq

With native SQL I can select, modify, and insert a record into a table like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (url, userName, id)
SELECT url, userName, '27AD2421-83B1-4872-A723-5BDF93688D7C'
FROM WebSite
WHERE id = '27AD2421-83B1-4872-A723-5BDF93688D7B'
```

This is particularly useful as the ID field is the primary key.

I would like to do the same thing in Java using JOOQ but I cant figure out how to provide the modified field value.

Is this possible, if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution for your problem

You can convert any value of type `T` to an expression of type `Field<T>` using [`DSL.val()`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/indexed-parameters/) (usually preferrable) or [`DSL.inline()`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/inlined-parameters/)

#### Explanation for the status quo

In a language that supports type aliases and untagged unions (e.g. TypeScript, Ceylon), the jOOQ API could be defined like this:

```java
// All of these are "column expressions"
type F<T> = T | Field<T> | Select<? extends Record1<T>> | ...;

interface DSLContext {
    <T1>         XYZ<Record1<T1>>         select(F<T1> field1);
    <T1, T2>     XYZ<Record1<T1, T2>>     select(F<T1> field1, F<T2> field2);
    <T1, T2, T3> XYZ<Record1<T1, T2, T3>> select(F<T1> field1, F<T2> field2, F<T3> field3);
}
```

But unfortunately, Java doesn't support this. The only option we have to emulate the above, which would allow for mixing `Field<T>` and `T` in argument lists would be a prohibitive amount of overloads (N^22 with N = number of types in `F<T>` and 22 being the maximum degree supported by jOOQ's type safety):

```java
interface DSLContext {

    // Still fine
    <T1>         XYZ<Record1<T1>>         select(T1        f1);
    <T1>         XYZ<Record1<T1>>         select(Field<T1> f1);

    // OK-ish
    <T1, T2>     XYZ<Record1<T1, T2>>     select(T1        f1, T2        f2);
    <T1, T2>     XYZ<Record1<T1, T2>>     select(T1        f1, Field<T2> f2);
    <T1, T2>     XYZ<Record1<T1, T2>>     select(Field<T1> f1, T2        f2);
    <T1, T2>     XYZ<Record1<T1, T2>>     select(Field<T1> f1, Field<T2> f2);

    // Problems start here
    <T1, T2, T3> XYZ<Record1<T1, T2, T3>> select(T1        f1, T2        f2, T3        f3);
    <T1, T2, T3> XYZ<Record1<T1, T2, T3>> select(T1        f1, T2        f2, Field<T3> f3);
    <T1, T2, T3> XYZ<Record1<T1, T2, T3>> select(T1        f1, Field<T2> f2, T3        f3);
    <T1, T2, T3> XYZ<Record1<T1, T2, T3>> select(T1        f1, Field<T2> f2, Field<T3> f3);
    <T1, T2, T3> XYZ<Record1<T1, T2, T3>> select(Field<T1> f1, T2        f2, T3        f3);
    <T1, T2, T3> XYZ<Record1<T1, T2, T3>> select(Field<T1> f1, T2        f2, Field<T3> f3);
    <T1, T2, T3> XYZ<Record1<T1, T2, T3>> select(Field<T1> f1, Field<T2> f2, T3        f3);
    <T1, T2, T3> XYZ<Record1<T1, T2, T3>> select(Field<T1> f1, Field<T2> f2, Field<T3> f3);
}
```

Because of this prohibitive complexity, jOOQ usually only offers API for either "all bind values" or "all expressions". In the case of `select()`, the "all bind variables" case is so rare that we decided to omit it:

```java
interface DSLContext {
    <T1>         XYZ<Record1<T1>>         select(Field<T1> f1);
    <T1, T2>     XYZ<Record1<T1, T2>>     select(Field<T1> f1, Field<T2> f2);
    <T1, T2, T3> XYZ<Record1<T1, T2, T3>> select(Field<T1> f1, Field<T2> f2, Field<T3> f3);
}
```